# Python modules scripts and import

Tags: python, import, module

Been on stack for sometime now but still can't wrap my head around python imports with scripts and modules.  Below is the dir setup with pack acting as the package, gdtsp the module and driver a driver script that imports and makes use of methods in the gdbtsp module.

```
└── pack
    ├── driver.py
    ├── gdbtsp.py
    ├── __init__.py
```

gdbtsp module has import statements, mostly numpy matplotlib stuff:
I have my methods wrap in a class so that gdbtsp looks like:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats as st

class Gdbtsp(object):
    def __init__(self, n, m):
        self.n, self.m = float(n), float(m)


    def gridCop(self):
        n = self.n

        X ,Y = np.mgrid[0.0:1.0:20j, 0.0:1.0:20j]
        first_value = np.zeros([len(X),len(Y)], dtype=float)
```

My issues:

running gdbtsp works fine as a script: python gdbtsp -> outputs fine.
On the other hand importing gdbtsp in driver.py or terminal does not work.

from pack import gdbtsp as gd

From what I can tell the import statements gets bound to the gd namespace, so I get stuff like
gd.np, gd.plt ... and driver terminates with a NameError: name 'np' is not defined.

How do you set up the import statement so that the module functions as a script as well.  Failing this how do you convert the script to a module?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: What is the code that is *not* working, and what is the full error traceback?

Comment: Has the driver module imported numpy as np? An import statement only makes the imported module available in the importing module. This is not like C/C++ includes -- importing a module gdbtsp will not make the module directly available to any module that imports gdbtsp.

Comment: Also code from driver would be helpful

Comment: Originally I had just on import statement for the module: from gdbtsplib import gdbtsp as gd.  I see now that I have to include those dependent import in the driver file as well. Adding the exact import statement from the modules to the driver solves the problem.

Comment: This seems like this can get messy.  How does usually specify these dependent modules for downstream applications that might want to use them?